# How can i enable git autocompletion in a conda environment?

Tags: git, conda

How can i activate git autocompletion in a conda environment which is running from a docker container?

I've tried to just install git with `conda install -c anaconda git` but
the autocompletion is not activated.

Comment: Neither conda nor docker are special here. Just install and activate autocompletion for your shell in the container. For bash it's `bash-completion`; `sudo apt install -y bash-completion && . /etc/bash_completion`

Comment: @phd i can't run those commands in the container ,i'm getting bash: bash-completion: command not found

Comment: What OS is running in the container? What shell?

Comment: @phd it's CentOs 7, bash is the shell

Comment: `sudo yum install epel-release && sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install bash-completion-extras` Found in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264240